# Docker with Selenium hub, Nodes, Loki and Grafana

Tags: python, docker, networking, grafana, grafana-loki

So I want to create docker-compose file which contains connected:
Selenium hub + his nodes + grafana + loki. The idea is to have the execution logs in grafana.

the docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  chrome:
    image: seleniarm/node-chromium
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    shm_size: 4gb
    depends_on:
      - selenium-hub
    environment:
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_HOST=selenium-hub
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_PUBLISH_PORT=4442
      - SE_EVENT_BUS_SUBSCRIBE_PORT=4443
      - SE_NODE_MAX_SESSIONS=3
      - SE_NODE_OVERRIDE_MAX_SESSIONS=true
      - SE_ENABLE_TRACING=true

  selenium-hub:
    image: seleniarm/hub
    container_name: selenium-hub
    ports:
      - "4442:4442"
      - "4443:4443"
      - "4444:4444"
    environment:
      - SE_ENABLE_TRACING=true
      - GRID_MAX_SESSION=18
      - GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT=240
      - GRID_TIMEOUT=240


  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail:2.2.0
    ports:
      - "9080:9080"
    volumes:
      - ./promtail-config:/etc/promtail
    command: -config.file=/etc/promtail/config.yml

  loki:
    image: grafana/loki:1.4.1
    ports:
      - "3100:3100"
    volumes:
      - /MyProjectOutsideTheNodes/Config/loki:/etc/loki
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - GF_EXPLORE_ENABLED=true
      - GF_LOGS_DATASOURCE=loki
    depends_on:
      - loki

volumes:
  esdata:
        driver: local
```

The config for promtail (config.yml)

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: http://loki:3100/loki/api/v1/push  # Use the service name "loki" as the URL

scrape_configs:
  - job_name: docker-containers
    pipeline_stages:
      - docker: {}
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - chrome-1   # Use the service names as targets
          - firefox
          - selenium-hub
        labels:
          job: varlogs
          host: $HOSTNAME
          __path__: /var/log/*.log
```

And the config for loki:

```
auth_enabled: false

server:
  http_listen_port: 3100

ingester:
  lifecycler:
    address: 127.0.0.1
    ring:
      kvstore:
        store: inmemory
      replication_factor: 1
    final_sleep: 0s
  chunk_idle_period: 5m
  chunk_retain_period: 30s
  max_transfer_retries: 0

schema_config:
  configs:
    - from: 2018-04-15
      store: boltdb
      object_store: filesystem
      schema: v11
      index:
        prefix: index_
        period: 168h

storage_config:
  boltdb:
    directory: /tmp/loki/index

  filesystem:
    directory: /tmp/loki/chunks

limits_config:
  enforce_metric_name: false
  reject_old_samples: true
  reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h

chunk_store_config:
  max_look_back_period: 0s

table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: false
  retention_period: 0s
```

If someone could help it will be awesome.  Sorry if the question is dumb, kinda new to this.

Expected behaviour: To be able to see the logs from the nodes in the Grafana

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was error in the config related to the places where the volumes are sleeping. closing.